# How do I center my navigation bar <LI> items CSS?

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I want my navigation bar to go 100% across the screen but the LIST items all stay to the left instead of centered, im sure its simple but I've been doing HTML and CSS for hours and my brain is no longer working :( help please?

```
.solidblocktheme{ /*additional mega drop down menu style for this theme*/
border:5px solid #cd0000;
padding:0; /*remove default padding inside mega menu*/
}

.solidblocktheme p, .solidblocktheme .column{
padding:5px; /*add padding inside p and .column elements within mega menu*/
width:auto;
}

.solidblockmenu{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 0;
float: left;
font: bold 15px Arial;
overflow: hidden;
margin-bottom: 1em;
border: 1px solid #625e00;
border-width: 1px 0;
background: black url(Images/blockdefault.gif) center center repeat-x;
}

.solidblockmenu li{
display: inline;
margin: 0 auto;
}

.solidblockmenu li a{
float: left;
color: white;
padding: 9px 11px;
text-decoration: none;
border-right: 1px solid white;
}

.solidblockmenu li a:visited{
color: white;
}

.solidblockmenu li a:hover, .solidblockmenu li a.selected{ /*Selected Tab style*/
color: white;
background: transparent url(Images/blockactive.gif) center center repeat-x;
}


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>New Website Layout</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssLayout.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ddmegamenu.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="ddmegamenu.js">

/***********************************************
* DD Mega Menu (c) Dynamic Drive (www.dynamicdrive.com)
* This notice MUST stay intact for legal use
* Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com/ for this script and 100s more.
***********************************************/

</script>

<script>

ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'solidmenu',
    dur:1000 //<--no comma after last setting
})


ddmegamenu.docinit({
    menuid:'megaanchorlink',
    dur:500,
    easing:'easeInOutCirc' //<--no comma after last setting
})

</script>
</head>

<body>



<ul id="solidmenu" class="solidblockmenu">
<li><a href="">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="">About Us</a></li>
<li><a href="">Images</a></li>
<li><a href="" rel="jkmenu">Events v</a></li>
<li><a href="">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>

<!--First mega menu (1) -->

<div id="jkmenu" class="mega solidblocktheme">

    <p style="margin:5px 0 10px 0"><b>Choose from our clubs events!</b></p>

    <div class="column">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="">Snooker</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Darts</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Poker</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Quiz</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Cabaret</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Adding HTML will help, and a Fiddle would be even better.

Comment: I've added my html now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
.solidblockmenu {
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     font: bold 15px Arial;
     overflow: hidden;
     margin-bottom: 1em;
     border: 1px solid #625e00;
     border-width: 1px 0;
     background: black url(Images/blockdefault.gif) center center repeat-x;
     text-align: center;
 }

 .solidblockmenu li {
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 .solidblockmenu li a {
     color: white;
     padding: 9px 11px;
     text-decoration: none;
     border-right: 1px solid white;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, pasted it straight in and it works and now I see why! :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing HTML it's difficult to be sure, as you've only posted the css, but if .solidblockmenu is the ul or ol, simply remove float: left; from it

Comment: I've added my html now, by the way the removing float left did not work! :(

Comment: you need to definitely remove float: left; from the ul to make it go 100%.  Also remove float: left; from the a tag within the li tags. Because of this float all the content is floated left, so your ul has 0 height.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand with what means your menu items should be centered by your opinion. I would recommend to get rid of all unneccessary `float:left`s, change `.solidblockmenu li` display to `inline-block` and add `text-align:center` to the `ul.solidblockmenu` itself